# Nifi: Need clarification on the Merge Content processor

Tags: csv, merge, apache-nifi

Because I don't think it works the way my supervisor think it works.

We're taking in a series of about 8 csv files from an FTP and these files are rather small (under 1MB). He's (rightfully, I think) concerned that cluster size on HDFS is going to be wasted. So he wants to use the Merge Content processor to resolve this. He seems to believe that the Merge Content processor will 'collate' files with the same name, making a bigger single file.

To clarify: The way he wants it to work is if today's "sales_report.csv" comes in and there's already a "sales_report.csv" existing in the directory, he wants the new data from today's "sales_report.csv" to be added as new rows to the existing file. I hope that makes sense.

Instead, I'm getting very different results. I have the flow set up so that it picks the files up from the FTP, creates a directory on HDFS based on the folder, and then a subfolder based on the year. When I leave the MC processor out, this all works perfectly. When I put the MC processor in, I get three files - one of them has its original name and two of them have a long string of random characters. We're using the default settings for the Merge Content processor.

Based on what I've described above it does it sound like the MC processor is what we're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MergeContent` processor works by combining multiple *flowfiles* into a single flowfile. This is *not* the same as appending new data to an existing file stored in HDFS (what your manager wants).

To accomplish this, you have a few options:

1. Keep your current flow without the `MergeContent` processor; you will still have the "small files" problem with HDFS.
2. Use a SQL-like interface to HDFS, such as [Hive](https://hive.apache.org/) (and optionally [HBase](https://hbase.apache.org/) ([why](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#arch.overview.hbasehdfs))). You can then consume the new data (today's *sales_report.csv*), and treat the rows in that file as [NiFi *records*](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/record-oriented-data-with-nifi) and persist them to the appropriate Hive table (effectively accomplishing an *append* operation).
3. Retrieve the existing *sales_report.csv* from HDFS, combine the contents with the new content using `MergeContent`, and persist the new merged content back to HDFS. This is a fairly wasteful operation, and not recommended. (See *Iterative Processing* in Alan Gates' [Pig and Hive at Yahoo!](https://yahoohadoop.tumblr.com/post/98256601751/pig-and-hive-at-yahoo)).

Which option you pursue is dependent on your specific requirements:

- Does the data need to be stored in the *same* file in HDFS, or just be accessible in the same directory?
- Does the data need to be stored in the original CSV file format, or is tabular storage acceptable?
- How large is the "existing" data stored in HDFS vs. the new incoming data?